# Flutter Meta SEO: Open Graph Tags are Failing

Tags: flutter, meta-tags, share-open-graph

I have successfully implemented Flutter meta_seo in my web app, and I can see the og tags using HTML *Inspect*, BUT not on *View page source*.

The problem is that when I use og tags preview tools like https://www.opengraph.xyz/, the tags are not visible; they are not visible on socials either. Is there anything I can do?

**View Page Source - OG Tags not Visible**

```
<base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="Permoja Collaboration and Community Platform.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="permoja">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>permoja</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

**Html Inspect - OG Tags are Visible**

```
<meta name="description" content="This is Women in HR summary">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="178043849885">
<meta property="og:title" content="Women in HR Kenya" data-rh="true">
<meta property="og:description" content="This is Women in HR summary" data-rh="true">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/f...jpg" data-rh="true">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Women in HR Kenya">

<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Women in HR Kenya">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="This is Women in HR summary">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b...jpg">
```

Comment: Same problem here, have you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. Probably an alternative approach is more feasible.